# How to implement rules with TTL in Makefile

Tags: makefile, ttl

Suppose I have a rule to build a big target and takes too long to run.
It does not have any dependencies.

For example, it could be a task to download some content from the Internet, like a web crawler that downloads lots of pages for later processing.

I want to generate the big target only if its latest run was more than 1 day/hour/minute ago. So the task has a TTL, time to leave.

I can accomplish it via this make file below.

If one makes the "all" target, then the big_target and small_target will only be made if it has passed more than 5 seconds since the last time they were built.

Does anyone has another suggestion or a canonical way of doing this with make?

```
.PHONY: all update_times
all: update_times big_target small_target

update_times:
    @for f in TTL_* ;\
    do\
        seconds=$${f##TTL_};\
        if (( `date +%s` - `date +%s -r $$f` > $${seconds} ));\
        then\
            echo "$$f is too old";\
            echo $$(( `date +%s` - `date +%s -r $$f` )) ;\
            rm $$f;\
        else\
            echo "$$f is up to date";\
        fi;\
    done

TTL_%:
    touch $@

big_target: TTL_5
    touch big_target

small_target: big_target
    touch small_target
```

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested method has some things I don't like: most prominently, it has an implied order relationship between the `update_times` and `big_target` targets, which is generally to be avoided (relationships in makefiles really need to be explicit, not implied).

I don't think there's any need for a different target.  Maybe something like this would work better?

(PS. TTL is generally "time to *live*", not "time to leave"):

```
big_target_TTL := 5

.PHONY: all
all: big_target small_target

big_target:
        secs=$$(( `date +%s` - `date +%s -r $@`)); \
        if [ $$secs -gt $($@_TTL) ]; \
        then \
            echo "$@ is too old"; \
            echo $$secs; \
            touch $@; \
        else \
            echo "$@ is up to date"; \
        fi

small_target: big_target
        touch small_target
```